# Find all primitives to the function $f(x)=x^{5/3}+\cos(5x)+e^{-3x}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Get all primitives to this function

$$f(x)=x^{5/3}+\cos(5x)+e^{-3x}$$

What is a primitive any way?

I answered

((x^(5/3)+1)/(5/3)+1)+C
sin(5x)+C
e^(-3x)+C

but it was wrong

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Some would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Find"), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Comment: When you think you have found an answer, you can differentiate it to check that you are right. Differentiation is easy, so it gives a quick check. And sometimes it gives you information that helps fix any errors.

Answer (score 1):

A primitive is just an anti-derivative as you initially suspected, but you didn't anti-differentiate properly. For example $\int \cos(5x)dx=\frac{1}{5}\sin(5x)+C$.

Comment: Is the answer (1/(5/3)+1)x^(8/3)+C+(1/5)sin(5x)+C-(1/3)c^(-3x) correct?